# How do I pass values from column rows to variable in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a SQL query like the following:

```
SELECT Name FROM Customers
```

My result is as follows:

```
Name
----
Customer1
Customer2
Customer3
Customer4
```

I need to pass the customer names to 4 different variables using C# as follows:

```
string cus1 = Customer1;
string cus2 = Customer2;
string cus3 = Customer3;
string cus4 = Customer4;
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a simple example to illustrate how to do it?

Comment: If you are returning your query results to a DataTable, you can get the query result from the DataTable.RowNumber.FieldNumber.

Comment: Dan, I thought about using the datatable method but didn't know how. Would you provide me a simple example for future use?

Comment: So  why did you accept the answer if you still searching for a better solution. @DanBracuk gave you a better way

Comment: I am learning C# and SQL and would like to know how to pass values from a Datatable to variables, I am sure that would be very helpful in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the data into a list, array, or similar. Here I'm using "dapper", but frankly anything would suffice (although `DataTable` would seems massively overkill for this):

```
List<string> names = conn.Query<string>("SELECT Name FROM Customers").ToList();

// then just consume them...
foreach(var name in names) {...}
string second = name[1];
// etc
```